# Modulo remainder equals to zero, only first two products taken into account in the loop

Tags: loops, python-3.x, modulo

I'm trying to find all the divisors ("i" in my case) of a given number ("a" in my case) with no remainder (a % i == 0). I'm running a loop that goes trough all the vales of i starting from 1 up to the value of a. The problem is that only first 2 products of a % i == 0 are taken into account. The rest is left out. Why is that?

Here the code in python3:

```
a = 999
i = 1
x = 0
d = []

while (i < a):
    x = a / i
    if(x % i == 0):
        d.append(i)
    i += 1

print (d)
```

The output of the code is:

```
[1, 3]
```

instead of listing all the divisors. 
I have checked for different values of a and can't find the error.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the script is correct. See for yourself:

[image]

I think it's your logic, and what you are trying to achieve is:

```
a = 999
i = 1
d = []

while (i < a):
    if(a % i == 0):
        d.append(i)
    i += 1

print (d)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 3, 9, 27, ...]
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton Sinyakin for giving the solution. I knew what the output was and I knew it was right. The question I meant why the loop stopped appending values after "i" reached the value of 3, even though it counted the and printed the values. I now see that the operation x = a / i was completely useless as a % i evaluates to exactly the same thing without this additional equation but if the code is ok, why it work the way it meant to?

Comment: @nao_de_naoned, the problem was that you do `x = a / i` and then you do `x % i` (not `a % i`). If you take `i = 9`, then in your case you get `x = 999 / 9 = 111` and then you try `111 % 9` which gives you `3` (instead of `999 % 9`, which should give you `0`). The script doesn't stop, it just doesn't find what you are looking for, since you are looking in the wrong place :)

Comment: I think I understand better now. In fact, x keeps its value instead of taking a new one at each iteration of the loop. It turns out I have learnt something new about the while loop : ). Thanks again @Anton Sinyakin.

Comment: No, you do assign a new value to `x` at each iteration, it's really just that your test was wrong: `a%i` is generally not the same as `x%i=(a/i)%i`.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Anton's answer, a more Pythonic way to loop would be:

```
a, d = 999, []
for i in range(1, a):
    if a%i == 0:
        d.append(i)
```

You can also take advantage of the fact that object have a [Boolean value](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__):

```
if not a%i:
```

Or you can use a list comprehension:

```
d = [i for i in range(1, a) if not a%i]
```